# Infer Generic Types of Superclass in Constructor TS

Tags: typescript

Typescript can infer generic types in certain instances:

```js
function add1<T extends string|number>(arg: T): T => arg + 1;
add1("5"); // Automatically becomes add1<string>("5")
add1(5);   // Automatically becomes add1<number>(5)
```

This also works in classes:

```js
class Add1er<T extends string|number> {
    constructor(public start: T){}
    add1 = () => this.start += 1;
}

new Add1er(5); // Automatically becomes new Add1er<number>(5)
new Add1er("5"); // Automatically becomes new Add1er<string>("5")
```

This does work with inheritance though in some cases:

```
class Add1er<T extends string|number> {
    constructor(public start: T){}
    add1 = () => this.start += 1;
}

class Add2er<T extends string|number> extends Add1er<T> {
  add2() {
    this.add1();
    this.add1();
  }
}

new Add2er("5"); // Add2er<string> extends Add1er<string>
```

Is there a setting that allows me to achieve this behavior when using `super`:

```
class Add2erWithStart extends Add2er {
    constructor() {
        super("5"); // Should show Add2er<string> 
    }
}
```